# ionic 4: dateStart and dateEnd have 2 hours difference

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using a little kind of code for saving local dateTime in localStorage for starting an account and closing it.

```
 //Save end date of cancelation action
this.WarrentItem.dateStart = this.timeNow;
this.WarrentItem.dateEnd = this.timeNow;
```

in my localStorage, i've got something like this.

Start date: 06/03/2019 07:00:00
End date: 06/03/2019 09:00:00

The problem is that is not two hours of difference. And im confused whats wrong.

Comment: how are you getting this.timeNow value?

Comment: @AbdulAzeem : public timeNow: Date = new Date();

Comment: this.WarrentItem.dateStart = new Date() 
                                                                                          
             this.WarrentItem.dateEnd = new Date()     try like this

Comment: @AbdulAzeem  : everything is the same. In localStorage i've got same time and when i send it to server, i've got 2 hours + of difference.

Comment: console log from storage in  that also two hour difference or only in server?

Comment: @AbdulAzeem : here you can see console log for dateStart and dateEnd and you will see that is the same: https://imgur.com/KcI0d9T

Comment: use new Date().toISOString()
and then send to server

Comment: @AbdulAzeem : 'toISOSString' doesnt exist on type 'string';

Comment: change your variable delcration to this public timeNow: String = new Date().toISOString()

Comment: @AbdulAzeem : its ok in declaration, but below in code i've got same error for: this.WarrentItem.dateStart = new Date().toISOString();

Comment: how have u declared this.WarrentItem.dateStart ?

Comment: @AbdulAzeem : look here in full ts file: http://dpaste.com/3CN5FMG

Comment: in WarrenModel u must have used Date change that to string

Comment: @AbdulAzeem : http://dpaste.com/3HPB9EJ warrentmodel.ts

Comment: yes change this dateStart: Date = null;
  dateEnd: Date = ''; to dateStart: String= null;
  dateEnd: String = '';

Comment: @AbdulAzeem : everything same.The time is not correct.

Comment: String = "" in place of string = null

Comment: @AbdulAzeem : nothing....same again.

Comment: may be issue is on the receiving side.Timezone issue maybe

Comment: @AbdulAzeem but how to fix it ?